# How to make dynamic join to tables in jpql query

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hql, jpql

I need to make dynamic joins to table as per the data in column.
e.g
table : to_dos

```
to_do_id | value | object_id | object_type
```

Now here object_type will be the table name and object_id will be primary key of that table, because my to_do table can have join with multiple table according to type of to_do

Now when I want to fetch to dos and its respective data from respective table I have following steps:

1-get todo data

2-get respective tables data in loop as per the object type

Can we do this without loop in JPQL, HQL or in Mysql? I need to avoid loop
Also please suggest if there is any more optimized way

Answer (score 0):

One solutio would be to use polymorphic associations between the `ToDo` entity and the related `ToDoTask` entity types.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TYPE")
public class Task {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Integer id;
  @ManyToOne
  private TaskList taskList;
  @Column(name = "TYPE", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
  private String type;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("TYPE1")
public class SubTaskType1 extends Task {}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("TYPE2")
public class SubTaskType2 extends Task {}

@Entity
public class ToDoList {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Integer id;
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "taskList")
  private List<Task> tasks;
}
```

Your code should then simply become:

```
ToDoList todos = todoRepository.findById( todoId );
for ( Task task : todos.getTasks() ) {
  // access task.getType() to get the discriminator type 
  // or
  // use instanceof to handle subclass casting
}
```